# Replace controller in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to replace the controller, depending on what env variables I get in startup. Can I do it after calling the

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    // Can I change or delete one of the links here?
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems to me that you are trying to find a way to replace a controller while solving another problem. Why do you need to replace the controller in the first place? Please share some more light on the underlying problems/goals, because then I think it will be more probable to offer you greater range of solutions, maybe even without the need of replacing the controller.

Comment: Is it perhaps more/less feasible to adapt the code inside a controller based on the environment variables, rather than entire controllers?

Comment: Hi @UDK, According to your description, perhaps you want to display the dynamic menu based on the env variables, right? If that is the case, you could try to use the [Environment Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/environment-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0), you can add hyperlinks in the environment tag, then based on the environment to render them. More detail information, see [Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0#environments).

Comment: Besides, you could also add `@if` condition to check the environment in the view, then render different menu, refer this link:[User Role Base Menu Management Using Dependency Injection](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-2-0-user-role-base-menu-management-using-dependency-injection/)